# What special variables can I use to adjust the behavior of cmake generated Makefiles?

Tags: makefile, cmake

Given a makefile generated by cmake, I found by trial and error that I can pass VERBOSE=1 to the make command for a more verbose build (in particular, actual compile commands are shown):

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

What other variables like this are supported by any makefile cmake generates?

Comment: "What other "standard" variables like this are supported by cmake makefiles?" - Everything which is *documented* or *described* somewhere. E.g. there is `DESTDIR` variable with the meaning like in autotools. What **sort of answers** do you want from us? The ones which lists **all known** variables? But "documentation" is not the purpose of the Stack Overflow. (In other words, your question is good ... but not for the Stack Overflow).

Comment: @Tsyvarev - one which listed all known variables would be fine. A pointer to documentation would be fine too (which, btw, is absolutely fine and good for SO as many questions are answered with reference to documentation: it's just not allowed to ask for documentation in your question). An answer which says VERBOSE is the only one guaranteed to be available with some backup would be fine, whatever.

Comment: "one which listed all known variables would be fine." - This is nothing else than a documentation-in-answer. Difference between your question and other questions, which are answered with reference to documentation, in that other questions have **practical purpose**, but your one has not such purpose. Compare: "How to force `make` to show actual compile commands?" - "Use `make VERBOSE=1`". And "What parameters I could pass to `make` so it will accept them?". The last question is a reformulation of the your one.